# Shortest Float32Array to Int32Array conversion for audio processing

Tags: code-golf, tips, javascript

I'm currently converting a `Float32Array` to an `Int32Array` for input to a real-time audio raw PCM to MP3 recording application.

```
new Int32Array([...new Float32Array(b)].map(f=>f<0?f*32768:f*32767)
```

The examples in the wild I've seen convert each float individually to avoid static, gaps, glitches when the audio recording is played back. I have a sense there is a way to do this without comparing each float, though I've seen no such examples in the wild for audio processing.

Looking at the I wonder is there a way to do this without comparing each float, basically, what is the shortest code to  convert a `Float32Array` to a `Int32Array` or `Int16Array` for audio processing?

Comment: Note that in general `Int32Array.from(new Float32Array(b), f => f * 32768)` or some such is generally more efficient than round-tripping through an intermediate array.

Comment: @Neil `8**5` reduces by 1 character.

Comment: @Neil We get glitches in the audio recording using either `f*32768` or `f*8**5`.

Comment: Sorry, I was just making a general efficiency comment, not a golfing suggestion. As such I just used a simple example. In particular I don't know what value range you're getting or what you're expected to map it to.

Comment: @Neil Your example is close. We get the correct result for the minimal example set `new Float32Array([-0.1, 1.0])` when we use `f*32767.5` https://gist.github.com/guest271314/15f027b20e2eaa082976f3a931cc5d2b. I'm recording a real-time MP3 in the browser https://github.com/guest271314/MP3Recorder/blob/media-capture-transform/MP3Recorder.js#L59-L63. I have not encountered a way to directly convert a `Float32Array` to `Int32Array`.

Comment: I found this [blog post](http://blog.bjornroche.com/2009/12/int-float-int-its-jungle-out-there.html) which shows how confusing this is. Out of those, I think the one used by PulseAudio seems to be the most straightforward.

Comment: @Neil I get the least clipping in the first few seconds of recording using what I have at OP or a variation thereof `Int32Array.from(floats, f=>f < 0 ? f * 32768 : f * 32767)`

Comment: @Neil We save a character using `32767` for `0x7FFF` and `32768` for `0x8000`.

Comment: @Neil Thanks for the link! [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78133607/is-it-possible-to-correctly-convert-float32array-to-int32array-without-testing-e/78136339#comment137747655_78133607) I was certain nobody would be crazy to do `float>0?float*0x7FFF:float*0x8000`, I stand corrected.

Comment: @Bergi You will find that same line in _a lot_ of audio processing code. Frankly I'm kind of surprised there is not a standardized method to do that conversion in JavaScript; at least in the Web Audio API domain.